# APEX Controller parameters size (bytes) limit in Lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have an `@AuraEnabled` method in my APEX controller that have a lot of parameters:

```
  @AuraEnabled
  public static String sendEmail(
    String    toAddresses,
    String    ccAddresses,
    String    bccAddresses,
    String    fromAddress,
    String    subject,
    String    content,
    String    attachments,
    String    externalAttachments,
    String    staticFiles,
    String    dynamicFiles
  ) {}
```

where `externalAttachments` is an array of objects (serialized) like this: `[{ type: '', name: '', data: /*base64 data*/ '' }]`

```
const payload = {
    fromAddress: '',
    toAddresses: JSON.stringify([]),
    ccAddresses: JSON.stringify([]),
    bccAddresses: JSON.stringify({}),
    subject: subject,
    content: contentEml,
    attachments: JSON.stringify([]),
    externalAttachments: JSON.stringify(filesCust),
    staticFiles: JSON.stringify([]),
    dynamicFiles: JSON.stringify([])
};
```

I used to work this way but since today, when there is a `externalAttachment`, the action (in JS controller) is fired and the callback is always called with a state of `error` **but the server never received a request** (in my logs).

Is there (until ?) a size limit, in byte, for the Lightning Controller <-> APEX Controller payload ?

Comment: Have you tried sending a very small attachment - just 1-2KB?

Comment: It works with a total of 1.2k ( multiple files) but last week I was able to send multiple 1.2mo files

Answer (score 2):

Whatever limit there is or isn't between the client and server, within the server Apex method the normal governor limits apply. So if your `@AuraEnabled` method is receiving several megabytes of base64 data and then tries to turn that data into a different format and so consume more big chunks of heap you will be at risk of hitting the 6M byte heap limit.

Comment: The thing is that the apex method is never reached..

Comment: @SimonPlacentino OK - an earlier limit. (There is the 6M HTTP request/response limit documented.) Might be worth using your browser's Developer Tools to examine the size of the request posted and experimenting to see what the threshold is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for an answer: The request payload includes all of the actions and their data serialized into JSON. The request payload limit is 4 MB.

Reference -
[1]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm#!